# How to go back in a new page using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I m using nodejs puppeteer to scrape a website. I've come across a situation where i need to go back in a new tab, but i couldn't find a way to do it in puppeteer (i can produce it manually on windows by `ctrl` + clicking the browser's go back button)

below is an example where i need to launch many pages in parallel starting from a particular page

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(myWebsiteUrl);
// going through some pages..

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPagesInParallel; i++) {
   // instanciating many pages with goback
   const newBackPage = await page.gobackAndReturnNewPage(); // this is what i wish i could do, but not possible in puppeteer
   const promise = processNewBackPageAsync(newBackPage);
   this.allPromises.push(promise);
}

await Promise.all([...this.allPromises])
```

Comment: Opened a issue in github: https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-protocol/issues/229

Answer (score 2):

I searched across puppeteer api and chrome devtools protocol and don't find any way to clone a tab or clone history to another tab, maybe this is a usefull feature to add to both puppeteer and chrome CDP.

But, there is a way to create a new page and go back in history without need to track history, the limitation of this solution is that the new page does not share/clone the history of original page, I also tried to use [Page.navigateToHistoryEntry](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-navigateToHistoryEntry) but since the history is owned by page I got a error

So, there is the solution that creates a new page and go to last history url.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function() {
    // headless: false
    // to see the result in the browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // let's do some navigation
    await page.goto("http://localhost:5000");
    await page.goto("http://localhost:5000/page-one");
    await page.goto("http://localhost:5000/page-two");

    // access history and evaluate last url of page
    const session = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    const history = await session.send("Page.getNavigationHistory");
    const last = history.entries[history.entries.length - 2];

    // create a new page and go back
    // important: the page created here does not share the history
    const backPage = await browser.newPage();
    await backPage.goto(last.url);

    // see results
    await page.screenshot({ path: "page.png" });
    await backPage.screenshot({ path: "back-page.png" });

    // uncomment if you use headless chrome
    // await browser.close();
})();
```

### References:

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-getNavigationHistory

Comment: "**the limitation of this solution is that the new page does not share/clone the history of original page**"         
this is unfortenately what i need. Your solution doesn't provide the same behaviour as manual `ctrl` + browser's back button.    
The back page in the website i'm scraping has a captcha. using your solution prompt me to a new captcha, while the manual `ctrl` + browser's back button prompt me to the same captcha, meaning i only solve one captcha for all my pages.    
I upvote your solution since it could help in other cases.

Comment: exactly, I will continue to find another way to do this (cloning history to page)... If I find it I will post another solution